# Make row number of cell in Libreoffice a variable

Tags: openoffice-calc, libreoffice

When I'am going to join two columns in the Libreoffice Calc, it seems that I have to do this by programming in Python for as far as I know, there is no way to index a cell by variable, specifically, to use a variable to denote the row number or column number.

I wonder whether there is no way to do this?

Many thanks if you could save me from write another temporary python script >_<

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I feel you may need the INDIRECT function.

You can try with

```
="Good Morning Mr,  " &INDIRECT("D" & A9)
```

which will give you

"Good morning, Mr White"

where  D9 contains string "White", and A9 contains  digit 9

Hope will help